# wmic - localized values

Tags: localization, wmic

When using the `wmic` command, it is possible to specify a locale using 
`/locale:ms_409` which means US English. I am using a German version of Windows XP, which displays some localized values when using querying information with `baseboard`. For example, when using the following commands, the locale does not to seem to make any difference. The value of `Tag` is displayed in English, while the one of `Caption` is displayed in German.
How do you have to use the locale in `wmic`? Is it not possible to display these localized values in English, which is (as I suppose) the original language? And if not, what is the use of the possibility of specifying the locale?

```
wmic:root\cli>context
NAMESPACE             : root\cimv2
ROLE                  : root\cli
NODE(S)               : COMP
IMPLEVEL              : IMPERSONATE
[AUTHORITY            : N/A]
AUTHLEVEL             : PKTPRIVACY
LOCALE                : ms_407
...

wmic:root\cli>baseboard  get caption, tag
Caption       Tag
Hauptplatine  Base Board

wmic:root\cli>/locale:ms_409 baseboard get caption, tag
Caption       Tag
Hauptplatine  Base Board

wmic:root\cli>context
NAMESPACE             : root\cimv2
ROLE                  : root\cli
NODE(S)               : COMP
IMPLEVEL              : IMPERSONATE
[AUTHORITY            : N/A]
AUTHLEVEL             : PKTPRIVACY
LOCALE                : ms_409
```

Answer (score 1):

*How do you have to use the locale in `wmic`?* You can get localized values only if a particular language is listed in `wmic /namespace:\\root\cli path __NAMESPACE`, for instance as follows:

**Result** (on my Windows, slightly edited): `437654test.bat`

> ```
> MS_409   US
> Caption     Tag
> Base Board  Base Board
>
> MS_408   Greek
> Caption         Tag
> Βασική πλακέτα  Base Board
>
> MS_419   Russian
> Caption         Tag
> Основная плата  Base Board
>
> MS_405   Czech
> Caption         Tag
> Základní deska  Base Board
> ```

**Explanation**: Apply `/trace:on` to diagnose the problem; note that in my Windows (default `MS_409`) isn't German language (`MS_407`) installed:

```
wmic /trace:on /locale:ms_407 baseboard get caption,tag
```

```
SUCCESS: IWbemLocator::ConnectServer(L"root\cli", NULL, NULL, L"ms_407", 0L, L"", NULL, -)
Line:    143 File: onecore\admin\wmi\wbem\tools\wmic\cmdalias.cpp

SUCCESS: CoSetProxyBlanket(-, RPC_C_AUTHN_DEFAULT, RPC_C_AUTHZ_NONE, NULL, 6, 3, -, EOAC_NONE)
Line:    162 File: onecore\admin\wmi\wbem\tools\wmic\cmdalias.cpp

FAIL: IWbemLocator::ConnectServer(L"root\cli\ms_407 not found. Connecting to ms_409", NULL, NULL, L"ms_407", 0L, L"", NULL, -)
Line:   2491 File: onecore\admin\wmi\wbem\tools\wmic\cmdalias.cpp

SUCCESS: IWbemLocator::ConnectServer(L"root\cli\ms_407", NULL, NULL, L"ms_409", 0L, L"", NULL, -)
Line:   2524 File: onecore\admin\wmi\wbem\tools\wmic\cmdalias.cpp

… (truncated) …
```

Moreover, only *localizable* properties are localized. The `Tag` property can't be localized because it has [Key Qualifier](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/key-qualifier) in the [Win32_BaseBoard class](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-baseboard)

```
SUCCESS: IWbemClassObject::Get(L"Name", 0, -, 0, 0)
Line:   1751 File: onecore\admin\wmi\wbem\tools\wmic\cmdalias.cpp
Result:  Tag

SUCCESS: IWbemClassObject::Get(L"Derivation", 0, -, 0, 0)
Line:   1767 File: onecore\admin\wmi\wbem\tools\wmic\cmdalias.cpp
Result:  Tag

SUCCESS: IWbemClassObject::Get(L"Description", 0,-, 0, 0)
Line:   1923 File: onecore\admin\wmi\wbem\tools\wmic\cmdalias.cpp
Result:  The Tag property uniquely identifies the base board of the system.
```

**The script:** `type 437654test.bat`

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "tokens=1" %%G in ('
       wmic /namespace:\\root\cli path __NAMESPACE get Name /Value
  ') do for /F "tokens=1,* delims==" %%g in ("%%~G") do (
          wmic /namespace:\\root\cli path __NAMESPACE where "%%~g='%%~h'"|findstr "%%~h"
          call :namespace "%%~h"
        )

:endlocal
ENDLOCAL
goto :eof

:namespace
  REM parameter %1 = namespace
  set "_ns=%~1"
  set "_lc=%_ns:~3%"
  set "_rk=HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layouts\00000"
  for /F "tokens=3*" %%P in ('
    reg query "%_rk%%_lc%" -v "Layout Text" ^|findstr /I "Layout.Text"
  ') do echo %%Q
  wmic /locale:%_ns% baseboard get Caption,Tag
  REM ,Description,Name
goto :eof
```